# How to make relative division take it's content height and width?

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with a relative division, I need it take it's content dimensions. 
I've tried some solutions proposed on others questions, like using flex-boxes, or table-columns, inline block or float, but none of theses solutions worked for me, because I'd have to put a max-width on the container or they will stay inline (I can't do that, if I do, I won't get the result wanted) and I'm not familiar with table displays.
I need it to be in relative position, but it's always taking the parents width and height. Sooo if you have any suggestion, I'll voluntarily hear them.

HTML

```
    <div class="main" id='mainContainer'>
        <div id="home" class="page_container homePage" name='Home'>
            <a class='arrow'></a>
            <div class='homePageSVG'></div>
            <div class='homepageTitle'><div><p class='Hname'>Monsieur Coco</p><p class='Hjob'>Développeur Web</p></div></div>
            <p class='noteDev'>Blablablabla</p>

        </div>.....other .page_containers</div>
```

CSS

```
.homepageTitle{
    left:50%;
    top :80%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 18;

    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-family: 'Avenir Next LT Pro Bold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 5.5em;

}

.homepageTitle > div,p{
    text-transform: lowercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}


.Hname{ 
}
.Hjob{
    font-size: .5em;
    border-top: solid thin;
    border-bottom: solid thin;
}
```

There is more CSS but it's mainly pseudo elements and I don't think they are of any use here, they are in the Fiddle though.

This is the wished result (absolute position) : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01parf8h/) 
This is the obtained result (relative position) : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud2Lxtx2/2/) 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Both examples look identical to me?

Comment: Yeah both are same :O

Comment: I failed when forking, I'm editing. Done, should be good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using display:flex and some shadow and gradient for the basis of the graphic part ?

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg,black 45%, transparent 45%),  
    linear-gradient(-45deg,black 45%, transparent 45%),  
    linear-gradient(-135deg,black 45%, transparent 45%),  
    linear-gradient(135deg,black 45%, transparent 45%) #096CA7;
}
body, main {
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 0.1em;
  width:0.75em;
  height:0.2em;
  box-shadow:0 0.05em 0 ,-0.5em -0.15em 0 -0.05em,0  -0.1em  ;
}
h1:after {
  box-shadow:0 0.05em 0 ,0.5em -0.15em 0 -0.05em,0  -0.1em  ;
}
p {
  box-shadow:0 -0.1em, 0 0.1em ;
  padding:0.1em;
  width:12em;
}
h1, p {
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Monsieur coco</h1>
<p>Dévelloppeur WEB</p>
</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks to you I found out how to use Flexboxes, as for the graphic parts, I'll try and eventually post a fiddle or a direct link to show the results.